# GKE autopilot events: Node is not ready: lack of PodCIDR?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, autopilot

GKE autopilot shows numerous kubernetes events: Node is not ready
Logs show:
Runtime network not ready: Network plugin is not ready: Kubenet does not have netConfig. This is most likely due to lack of PodCIDR

Nodes show PodCIDR: of 2^(32-26=6)=64 IP addresses (see below)

I have ~30 cronjobs running at various intervals from 1 minute to 1 day.
I have 2 services
The workloads show no errors or warnings
GKE Version 1.28.3-gke.1286000

I added secondary IP address ranges following
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/multi-pod-cidr#add_more_pod_ranges_autopilot
and
[GKE autopilot with shared vpc ip exhausted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75166260/gke-autopilot-with-shared-vpc-ip-exhausted)

```
Pod IPv4 address range (default)    10.84.0.0/17        
Cluster pod IPv4 ranges (additional)    
pvlivesecondaryipv4range2 (10.0.0.0/16)
pvlivesecondaryipv4range3 (240.10.0.0/17)
```

I expected the nodes to use the secondary IP ranges (Cluster pod IPv4 ranges (additional)).
The Cluster manifest Cluster pod IPv4 ranges tool tip says
"GKE will allocate a pod range from the list of default and additional pod ranges to node pools automatically"

The nodes seem to not use the secondary IP ranges.

```
$ kubectl describe node  | egrep 'Name:|PodCIDR|CreationTimestamp:'
Name:               gk3-pvlive-autopilot-pool-2-3a70ba4f-khfj
CreationTimestamp:  Tue, 16 Jan 2024 09:53:01 +0000
PodCIDR:                      10.84.0.64/26
PodCIDRs:                     10.84.0.64/26
Name:               gk3-pvlive-autopilot-pool-2-3b206b5e-hsw5
CreationTimestamp:  Tue, 16 Jan 2024 10:11:02 +0000
PodCIDR:                      10.84.0.0/26
PodCIDRs:                     10.84.0.0/26
Name:               gk3-pvlive-autopilot-pool-2-3b206b5e-rmpd
CreationTimestamp:  Tue, 16 Jan 2024 10:08:56 +0000
PodCIDR:                      10.84.0.192/26
PodCIDRs:                     10.84.0.192/26
Name:               gk3-pvlive-autopilot-pool-2-472e39ca-kspl
CreationTimestamp:  Tue, 16 Jan 2024 08:44:54 +0000
PodCIDR:                      10.84.1.0/26
PodCIDRs:                     10.84.1.0/26
$
```

How can I fix the issue causing the kubernetes events and log warnings?
Should I ignore the events and log warnings?
Thanks

Comment: What's the CIDR you assigned to nodes? And how many are used and how many are available?

Comment: GKE Autopilot assigns CIDRs to the nodes from a pool.  The default pool: 10.84.0.0/17 (32k addresses);  additional pools that I added: pvlivesecondaryipv4range2 (10.0.0.0/16) (64k addresses); pvlivesecondaryipv4range3 (240.10.0.0/17) (32k addresses). How many are used? ~100. $ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | wc
     95     582   11127

Comment: Do you have any additional webhooks you deployed yourself ? https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting/container-runtime

Comment: No additional webhooks I have deployed myself.